# Why is Mustafar "where Jedi go to die"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

At the end of the first season of Star Wars Rebels

> Tarkin takes Kanan to Mustafar to extract information.

When asked about the planet, Hera says

> I've only heard that name once, from Kanan. He said Mustafar is where Jedi go to die.

Is there anything else in the current Disney canon to corroborate this?

Kanan wouldn't have known about the duel between Obi Wan and Vader so he wouldn't be referring to that.

Is this referring to something yet to be revealed?

Comment: DOnt have a refference but i think that there is a refference to the Emperor having a secret lab on Mustafar. It could have been a place where captured Jedi were sent to be experimented on or converted or some such. Cant remember but i think i read about this in one of the early rulebooks or something...

Comment: Mustafar was one of the Separatists bases. It's possible that they had a track record of killing lots of Jedi.

Comment: In both those cases it seems like they would be sent. Go to implies that there is choice. Perhaps I'm reading too much into it.

Comment: I'll wait till Dec 18. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the canon novel *Star Wars: Aftermath*:

> After all, didn't Mustafar hold some importance to the Imperial leadership? Rumors said that's where Vader took some of the Jedi long ago. Torturing them for information before their execution. -Wedge Antilles

Because this information was so well known that it became a rumor, I would say that Kanan and Hera were referencing that.

I predict that this will be explored further in the future.

### Update:

*Rogue One* shows that

> Darth Vader has [a castle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vader's_personal_abode) on Mustafar, furthering this storyline.

Comment: Rebels also shows that force sensitive children were captured and sent there.

Comment: The force sensitive children kidnapping storyline is a continuation of a storyline in Clone Wars, where children were also being captured and sent to Mustafar. Season 2, Episode 3 - "Children of the Force".

Answer (score -1):

The commenters are right. The Emperor had a secret lab at one point. But you also have to remember that Darth Vader was once man named Anakin Skywalker, who was a Jedi. Darth Vader killed him and rose up in his place. Mustafar is the place where Jedi die.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFFSE!  This does not address the question insofar as it is a circular argument.  Please refrain from using answers as comments

Comment: We know from other sources that Anakin supposedly died in the Jedi temple during the initial assault

Comment: Not exactly. He actually could of been saved. But then he saw obi wan